# Reloading Javascript after AJAX JSF request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

Well, I'm using the TinyMCE editor and when i try to open a modal dialog the tinyMCE isn't rendered.

Look:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.tinymce').on('show',function(e){
        initTinymce();
    });

});

function initTinymce(){
    tinymce.init({
        selector: ".tinymce",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
    }); 
}
```

My page:

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label>Conteúdo *</label>
                                <h:inputTextarea value="#{cursoMB.paginaConteudo.conteudo}"
                                    id="conteudo" required="true"
                                    requiredMessage="O conteúdo é obrigatório"
                                    styleClass="form-control tinymce">
                                </h:inputTextarea>
                            </div>
```

My ajax call:

```
<h:commandButton styleClass="btn btn-default" type="button"
                            value="Criar Página"
                            actionListener="#{cursoMB.novaPaginaConteudo()}">
                            <f:passThroughAttribute name="data-toggle" value="modal" />
                            <f:passThroughAttribute name="data-target"
                                value="#modalDialogPagina" />
                            <f:ajax execute="@this" render="modalPagina" />
                        </h:commandButton>
```

How can i fix this ?

**EDIT 1**

I tried using jsf.ajax.addOnEvent but didn't work too, the tinyMCE is not rendered (console.log is showed normal):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    initTinymce();
    jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(ajaxHandleTinymce);
});

function ajaxHandleTinymce(data){
    console.log('ajaxHandle');
    initTinymce();
}

function initTinymce(){
    tinymce.init({
        selector: ".tinymce",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
        ],
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must init your widget after the ajax call, you could attach a javascript event listener on the `f:ajax` in this way:

```
<f:ajax execute="@this" render="modalPagina" onevent="handleAjaxResponse"/>

function handleAjaxResponse(data) {
   if (data.status === 'success') {
      initTinymce();
   }
}
```

I don't recommend to use the  jsf.ajax.addOnEvent callback for your case because the widget will be init each time an ajax call is made to the server.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. The tinyMCE is not rendered. I putted a console.log in handleJaxResponse() and this is called normally.

Comment: Could be a problem with the initTinymce()  function could you execute the function initTinymce() manually in the console of the browser after the ajax call to check if there is an error shown

Comment: Well, i executed the "initTinymce()" in console and got: undefined. If i execute "initTinymce" i got the code of function as return

Comment: yes that is ok it shows undefined because the function not return a value, but the widget was showed correctly after executing the function initTinymce();

Comment: unhappy no, when i execute the initTinymce() in browser console, the modal dialog widget continue without the editor.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your selector check if the element rendered you want to create  has the class="tinymce" attribute, or test with other selector as tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73526/discussion-between-shelly-and-cesar-loachamin).